# hard-link inode behaviour

Tags: hard-link

```
bash: ~/Desktop $ mkdir DIR  
bash: ~/Desktop $ cd DIR  
bash: ~/Desktop/DIR $ echo 000_111 > fileA  
bash: ~/Desktop/DIR $ ln fileA fileB  
bash: ~/Desktop/DIR $ cat fileA fileB  
000_111  
000_111  
bash: ~/Desktop/DIR $ ls -i  
6298182 fileA  6298182 fileB  
bash: ~/Desktop/DIR $ ls -il  
total 8  
6298182 -rw-r--r-- 2 da7id da7id 8 ott 19 16:58 fileA  
6298182 -rw-r--r-- 2 da7id da7id 8 ott 19 16:58 fileB  
bash: ~/Desktop/DIR $ mv fileB /$HOME/Desktop/fileB  
bash: ~/Desktop/DIR $ ls -il  
total 4  
6298182 -rw-r--r-- 2 da7id da7id 8 ott 19 16:58 fileA  
bash: ~/Desktop/DIR $ ls -il '/home/da7id/Desktop/fileB'   
6298182 -rw-r--r-- 2 da7id da7id 8 ott 19 16:58 /home/da7id/Desktop/fileB
```

`fileA` and `fileB` still have the same inode even if I moved `fileB` from `/$HOME/Desktop/DIR/fileB` to `/$HOME/Desktop/fileB`

What is the hard-link exact behaviour in this case?

Comment: The behavior is what is expected from hard link, read the documentation!

Answer (score 4):

Your `fileA` and `fileB` are just two directory entries pointing to the same inode, and thus, to the same file. Renaming the file, or moving it within the same filesystem does not change this relationship.

A file can have an arbitrary number of names, but only exactly one inode number, and no other file in the same filesystem can have the same inode number.

Special case: a file with *zero* names will exist only as long as it is held open.